# Flag outgoing message for follow-up in Thunderbird

Tags: email, thunderbird

More and more I need to follow up on specific messages I have sent, but memory fades. Can anyone recommend a way to flag outgoing messages "for follow-up" in Thunderbird? (Not sure but I think MS Outlook supports this.)

I have a little hack, which involves a custom rule to tag incoming messages from myself to myself. Then I simply include myself in the recipient list on messages I want to follow up on. But perhaps there is a more elegant extension or technique out there?

Comment: Does putting a label on the outgoing in the Sent folder not do?

Comment: Well yes, that's what I do, but it's an extra step.

Comment: I found this: https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/thunderbird/addon/follow-up/
Cheers,
Rv

Comment: possible duplicate of [Track unanswered mails in Thunderbird](http://superuser.com/questions/377909/track-unanswered-mails-in-thunderbird)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in the absence of any responses I will continue using tags and rules.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install "Lightning" extension (calendar, tasks).
2. Select email you want to follow-up/track.
3. Make a right mouse click.
4. Select from pop-up menu "Convert To" -> (event|task)