# Is there a way to search for all the emails that you sent but that you haven't gotten a response to?

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-365

I thought it might be kind of a useful thing to be able to search for people who need "as per my last email" to find out what gets lost in the bin without a reply.

[image: man punching with words as, per, my last, email]

Is there a way to search for this simple stupid functionality that really should be a much accessible feature in Outlook 365?

Comment: A similar question for Thunderbird has suggestions others found useful: https://superuser.com/questions/377909/track-unanswered-mails-in-thunderbird . You can open Outlook email in Thunderbird, if there is no native solution.

Answer (score 1):

According to my research, there doesn't seem to be a default setting for tracking unanswered messages in the Outlook client.
However, you can check “Show as conversation” under “View” to easily see the recipients' replies when viewing the messages.
Or you can also click Options and expand Tracking on the ribbon when creating a new message to choose "Request Delivery Receipt" and "Request Read Receipt".

Comment: hi @leeand00,Just wanted to check if the answer shared below helped. If it helped, then would request you to please "Accept the answer" as it would be helpful to others in the community as well.